# JMeter plugin - what is "jpgc - Standard Set" plugin

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In `JMeter Plugins Manager` there's an option to add "jpgc - Standard Set"

> Virtual package, select to install its dependencies

What is the usage of such plugin ? is it the default plugin for some flow? is it internal plugin?

I don't find any documentation on it in https://jmeter-plugins.org

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s virtual in the sense that it is not a plugin but a way to install a set of plugins by using dependencies installation mechanism :

- jpgc-dummy => Dummy Sampler
- jpgc-casutg => Thread groups
- jpgc-tst => Throughput Shaping Timer
- jpgc-graphs-basic=> 3 basic graphs
- jpgc-ffw => Flexible File writer
- jpgc-fifo => Inter-Thread communication
- jpgc-perfmon => perfmon
- jpgc-function => functions of jpgc

I guess it exists because historically, plugins were distributed in 3 bundles:

- standard
- extra
- full

Comment: Why those plugins are a set?